# Rails - Any plugins for building a online quiz/test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm trying to add some online tests to my site and before I rolled up my sleeves I was wondering if there is any ruby on rails plugin support for such a task.

Essentially I'm looking for something that lets me add multiple choice questions.  Performing the scoring logic would be an added bonus.

Any one know of anything?

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Bates has a screencast on [nested model forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) where the example app is a survey tool You could use it as a starting point.